# Can you use the chart web part to display frequency information?

Tags: chart-web-part

I have a list of data with each record including a user ID and some numeric data.

I would like to have a chart that shows the number of records for each user ID. Is that possible with the chart web part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there's no such functionality out of the box. But I can imagine a custom connected webpart that will not have any UI but will only process your list records and return desired data via webpart connections. Chart Webpart allows such data source. You can also create BCS external list and custom provider for it with the same idea because it's the second data source type for Chart Webpart that give you a place to write some code but I think the custom webpart will be faster and easier to implement.